# PHP MVC: 404 error when action-methodname contains show

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, actionmethod

I have a very strange problem in my current custom PHP MVC project. If a controller methodname contains show (fx show_album), apache throws a 404 page not found?

Du you have any ideas why this happens?

.htaccess:

```
#mod_rewrite start
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]
#mod_rewrite end
```

Btw. it works with normal get request in url (like index.php?controller=profile&action=show_album&id=1

Comment: Sure it's not the `_`, since your patterns seem to match only A-Z (not underscores)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is likely not to be the word `show` and more likely to be the underscore in `show_album` - your patterns in `htaccess` won't match underscores.

Try the following patterns with underscores added.

```
#mod_rewrite start
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]*)/?([a-zA-Z_]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]
#mod_rewrite end
```